# Por que em "Rosa" se acentua o "o" e em "Ronaldo" se lê o "o" como "u"?

Tags: português-europeu, pronúncia, acentuação

Por que em "Rosa" se acentua o "o" e, em Portugal, em "Ronaldo" se lê o "o" como "u"? No Brasil, se acentua o "o" em Ronaldo? Qual a regra?

Comment: CIMend, editei a tua pergunta tentando torná-la mais clara. Se quiseres ela como antes, por favor, edita a tua pergunta de volta ou me falas que eu o faço.

Comment: Nem Rosa nem Ronaldo tem "u".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Parece-me que a sua pergunta é sobre **acento principal**.

Há regras para determinar o acento principal numa palavra portuguesa, mas para mim as duas regras principais são:

1. Se há acento gráfico, o acento principal está lá.
2. Se não, busque a última consoante que não é um "s" ou "m" no fim da palavra (te[s]e e te[s]es, não tese[s]). O acento principal está no vogal que precede (t[e]se).

(Há mais informações no [Acordo Ortográfico](http://www.portaldalinguaportuguesa.org/acordo.php?action=acordo&version=1990), mas as duas regras em cima servem para quase todas as palavras multi-sílabas usadas nesta resposta — acho que só não explicam "-ais" e "-ão".)

As últimas consoantes são Ro[s]a e Ronal[d]o, então os acentos principais são R[o]sa e Ron[a]ldo.

A letra "O", quando não tem o acento principal, tem a tendência de se pronunciar "U". Esta pode variar com o sotaque do falante.

O acento principal não obriga o falante a encurtar todas as outras sílabas de forma igual; é possível "carregar" noutras sílabas. Acho que há um exemplo mesmo na palavra "principal": enquanto o "a" tem a acento principal e os "i"s não, acho que o "i" primeiro não se encurta mesmo que o outro. Assim no "Ronaldo", é possível o "o" primeiro não encurtar como o último.

Comment: So nice to have a response like yours. I will now remove my initial remark. I was having major issues on another forum with this type of thing. Cheers.

Comment: Acho que "-ais" e "ão" são contrações do que originalmente eram duas sílabas: "ales" e "ano" (veja-se noutras línguas: principales, capitano). Isto explica que o acento esteja na última sílaba e não na penúltima - o que era a penúltima sílaba tinha o acento, e ao fundirem as sílabas o acento naturalmente manteve-se.

Comment: Uma nota: em pt-PT, chamamos a isto a sílaba tónica.

Comment: As vogais nasais como em *pr**in**cipal* (o ene não tem valor consoante, apenas indica nasalação do i) nunca são reduzidas (estas reduções na pretónicas ocorrem em Portugal mas não no Brasil). Mas os advérbios em -*mente* são um bom exemplo: o primeiro *a* é aberto em *v**a**go* (em que é tónico) e também em *v**a**gamente* (em que não é). Depois há palavras avulsas (uso acento grave para indicar timbre aberto): *p**à**teta, g**è**ração* (pronúncia tradicional; ja há gente, em Portugal, a reduzir o *é* de *geração). E eu sou daqueles que pronuncia *Rònaldo*, sem reduzir o primeiro *ó* a u.